Missing data in longitudinal study; SPSS; Python
I have a dataset in psychology field with 3 measurement points (longitudinal data), 4 questionnaires, and about 120 participants. There is a lot of missing data in this dataset. I need to clean the data and prepare it for correlations, MANOVAs, etc... If I delete all the participants, less than half of the sample is left. Furthermore, I need to work with the same sample for all questionnaires (I think). Still, the data is diffuse: For example: a participant has completed all questionnaires (A, B, C), except for questionnaire D, where he skipped observations 2 and 3. In this case, they can be included in the sample for questionnaires A, B, C, but what to do with the fact that he didn't participate in observations 2 and 3 for questionnaire D? Should the person be deleted completely or only for the analysis of questionnaire D, won't this ruin the sample?
Interpolation is not possible in this case. Imputation is also unlikely to give reliable results.
-> The easiest way seems to be to delete the data, but this will reduce the sample dramatically...
So how do we deal with missing data in longitudinal data? I work with SPSS, but also R or Python would be fine.

Why is imputation unlikely to give reliable results? The typical solutions are imputation or Full Information Maximum Likelihood (FIML), but these are asymptotically equivalent, so much of the time the choice doesn't matter.
Both interpolation and deleting data seem like a bad idea.

Deleting the data doesn't just reduce the sample size, it also potentially biases your results.
